# I have a dynamic value in response but it keep on changing the position. How can i capture it

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-4.0

I have a dynamic value in response but it keep on changing the position. How can i capture it.
ex:1st iteration value is 2nd position
   2nd iteration value is 4th position
   3rd iteration value is 1st position...like that

Can you some one please guide me how to capture this value using Regular Expression Extractor or any other Extractor.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Regular Expression Extractor is not the best choice, [especially when it comes to HTML response type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748) so make sure to use the suitable [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), i.e.

- HTML - [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter)
- XML - [XPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)
- JSON - [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)
- Anything else: [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) might be easier to use than the Regular Expression Extractor

Going forward include (at least partial) response in your question and indicate which value you want to extract so we could come up with the most efficient approach.

Answer (score -1):

As of JMeter 3.0, it’s far easier to extract data from JSON responses using the JSON variable extractor. JSON is an extremely simple data format which has taken over XML a few years ago.

An increasing number of REST APIs and servers, are using JSON as their primary data exchange format. Here, we will use JMeter to parse the JSON response.
Suppose we have a JSON response as follows:

```
     {
        "store": {
            "book": [
                {
                    "category": "reference",
                    "author": "Nigel Rees",
                    "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                    "price": 8.95
                },
               {
                    "category": "fiction",
                    "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                    "title": "Sword of Honour",
                    "price": 12.99
                }
            ],
            "bicycle": {
                "color": "red",
                "price": 19.95
            }
        },
        "expensive": 10
    }
```

To parse the above JSON with JMeter, we need to add the JSON Extractor to our test plan.

Right click on Test Plan –> Add –> Post Processors –> JSON Extractor

jmeter json extractor parser

Now, we should see the following view:

json extractor jmeter

In the JSON Path expressions field, we can insert our JSON path to parse the JSON response

Here are some example Json Path expressions that can be used to extract data from the Json document exposed above:

```
JSONPATH    RESULT
$.store.book[*].author  The authors of all books
$..author   All authors
$.store.*   All things, both books and bicycles
$.store..price  The price of everything
$..book[0,1]    The first two books
$..book[:2] All books from index 0 (inclusive) until index 2 (exclusive)
$..book[2:] Book number two from tail
$..book[?(@.isbn)]  All books with an ISBN number
$.store.book[?(@.price < 10)]   All books in store cheaper than 10
$..book[?(@.price <= $[‘expensive’])]   All books in store that are not “expensive”
$..book[?(@.author =~ /.*REES/i)]   All books matching regex (ignore case)
$..*    Give me every thing
$..book.length()    The number of books
```